# How to show Woocommerce product per label as per my wish?

Tags: wordpress

[image]

Please see the photo. Here showing 3 products by default. Here I want to keep 4 products per label. Product container contain more space for per product. I also want to reduce this space for keep more products per label.
How can I keep 4 products per label? Please help me experienced man....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your functions.php file should work, it should change the 3 products per row to 4 products.

```
// Change number or products per row to 4
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) 
{
    function loop_columns() 
    {
        return 4; // 4 products per row
    }
}
```